# prolog how to connecting data using loop/recursion

Tags: loops, recursion, prolog

I got data which is from

```
father(adam, matt).
father(matt,frank).
father(frank,jim).

grandfather:-father(X,A),father(A,Y).
```

How do I actually using a recursion to search the grandfather or maybe great grandfather? basically mean X to Y using a loop.

Edit: and all possible matches, as there more to one father and son's

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the [exact function you need](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Recursive_Rules) is the first Google result for 'prolog recursion':

For reference, you can use the left hand side of a rule in the right hand side, and you get recursion.

Comment: i forgot to mention to list out all possible with backtracking. 
for now  ` search(X,Y):- father(X,A),write(X),write(' is father to '),write(A),nl,linkedcity(A,Y),write(' is father to '). but it only list out 1 possible.